# GitLab CI Script variables

Tags: yaml, gitlab

I have gitlab deployment activem and I want to get the deploy script to have some custom information about the deployment process (like `$CI_PIPELINE_ID`).

However, the script doesn't get the variables, instead it gets the "raw text".

> the call performed by the script is: `$ python deploy/deploy.py $CI_COMMIT_TAG $CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL $CI_PIPELINE_ID`

How can i get it to use the variables?

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:2.7

before_script:
  - whoami
  - sudo apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - sudo chmod +x deploy/deploy.py
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
      - tags
      - trigger
  except:
      # - develop
      - /^feature\/.*$/
      - /^hotfix\/.*$/
      - /^release\/.*$/

  script:
    - python deploy/deploy.py $CI_COMMIT_TAG $CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like potentially that you could be using a different environmental variable that you should be using.

- `bash/sh         $variable`
- `windows batch   %variable%`
- `PowerShell      $env:variable`

See [using CI variables in your job script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean with "raw text", but you can declare the variables in your project settings. Also, have you configured you're runner?

Go to `Settings->CI/CD->Secret Variables` and just put them right there.

You can also find valuable information in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html).